# Continuously input JavaScript values into password entry with onclick function?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

How can I continuously input password values using javascript onclick function into password field?

I have two 'Blue' and 'Red' images that work with the onclick function and have the values below;

```
Blue= w3!
Red= T4.
```

When I click on the Blue image it inputs the value 'w3!' into the password field. But   when I then click on the Red image, it replaces the the input and becomes 'T4' in the password field. HOW CAN I attach the Red input wit the blue to become 'w3!T4' in the password field, instead of replacing it? Pls I need help here...thx.
Below are my code Entries:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>    
 # red
 {width:50px;
  height:50px;
  }
 # blue
 {width:50px;
  height:50px;
  }
 </style>

 <script src="javascript/myred.js"></script>
 <script src="javascript/myblue.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

 <img id="red" src="images/items/blue_in.jpg" alt="no blue" onclick="myblue()">
 <img id="blue" src="images/items/red_in.jpg" alt="no red" onclick="myred()">

 <label for="password">Passcode:</label>
 <input name="password" type="password" id="password">

 </body>
 </html>
```

My JavaScript files stored in my server are seen below;

For myblue:

```
  function myblue()
  {
  x=document.getElementById("password");  // Find the element
  x.value="w3!";    // add the content
  }
```

For myred:

```
  function myred()
  {
  x=document.getElementById("password");  // Find the element
  x.value="T4";    // add the content
  }
```

Please, how can I add the value of the blue image into the password field without replacing the red input...cheers.. comments are welcomed..

Comment: Do I sense some bruteforce web tool in the making?

Comment: not really, but doing a research on similar...

Comment: There's no jquery code, just ordinary Javascript, removed that tag.

Comment: @Barmar. Thanks for editing...didn't take notice..cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+=`

```
function myblue()
  {
  x=document.getElementById("password");  // Find the element
  x.value += "w3!";    // add the content
  }

function myred()
  {
  x=document.getElementById("password");  // Find the element
  x.value += "T4";    // add the content
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myblue()
{
  x=document.getElementById("password");  // Find the element
  x.value += "w3!";    // add the content
}
```

that solution, of course, appends the string meanining it could be "w3!w3!w3!T4!" depending on how often you click it.

```
function myblue()
{
  x=document.getElementById("password");  // Find the element
  if(x.value.indexOf('w3!') < 0){
    x.value += "w3!";    // add the content
  }
}
```

use this approach if you only want the values once. Of course you have to alter this functions to work as `myred()`